# oracle : limit the varchar2 to 12 for phone number

Tags: oracle, constraints, ddl, varchar2

I am trying to impose a constraint to fix the length of phone numbers to 12, but the code fails:

```
create table customer (
rollcall number CONSTRAINT rc_pk PRIMARY KEY,
fname varchar(2) not NULL,
lname varchar(2)  not NULL,
phone varchar2(13) check (length(phone))=12 
);
```

Comment: Better to include the actual error message than to just say "the code fails"

Comment: Error starting at line : 18 in command -
create table customer (
rollcall number CONSTRAINT rc_pk PRIMARY KEY,
fname varchar2(20) not NULL,
lname varchar2(20)  not NULL,
phone varchar2(13) (check (length(phone)<=12) )
)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I would have tried insert before and update before triggers and handled this logic there.(you can append + or whatever from that). It would be better and you can disable/update them as per your convenience without touching the definition. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Just define the maximum length to 12 - it would be much easier:

```
create table customer (
    rollcall number CONSTRAINT rc_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    fname varchar(2) not NULL,
    lname varchar(2)  not NULL,
    phone varchar2(12)
);
```

EDIT:

Now that the question has been reworded to explain that the length of the field should be **exactly 12 characters**, it's clear that you do, in fact, need a check constraint. The issue in your original snippet was a misplacement of the closing bracket. The following snippet shows the correct placement, with the entire condition enclosed in the check clause's brackets:

```
create table customer (
    rollcall number CONSTRAINT rc_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    fname varchar(2) not NULL,
    lname varchar(2)  not NULL,
    phone varchar2(12) check (length(phone) = 12) -- here
);
```

Comment: I want to limit the constraint because I will append + later while saving.

Comment: @Nigel: But won't your constraint fail when you try to add `+` as the 13th character?